# uncaught exception: Template undefined not found, ReferenceError: Backbone is not defined

Tags: ruby-on-rails, templates, backbone.js, coffeescript, marionette

I am trying to follow along with this series:

http://www.backbonerails.com/series/engineering_single_page_apps

I am on episode 5, at around the 48 min mark. When I refresh the page in my browser, I get this in the firebug console:

`uncaught exception: Template undefined not found`

I tried running my code at http://coffescript.org, and I get this error:

`ReferenceError: Backbone is not defined`

I'm not sure, but I'm guessing the above error is just occurring because the coffescript.org console doesn't know what Backbone is.

Here is the relevant code:

show_controller.js.coffee

```
@Demo.module "FooterApp.Show", (Show, App, Backbone, Marionette, $, _) ->

  Show.Controller =

    showFooter: ->
      console.log "footer"
      footerView = @getFooterView()
      App.footerRegion.show footerView

    getFooterView: ->
      new Show.Footer
```

With the above code, I notice in the console that **"footer" is not appearing as it should.** So maybe something is wrong with the controller? Or something within the "showFooter" method.

list_controller.js.coffee

```
@Demo.module "HeaderApp.List", (List, App, Backbone, Marionette, $, _) ->

  List.Controller =

    listHeader: ->
      console.log "header"
      headerView = @getHeaderView()
      App.headerRegion.show headerView

    getHeaderView: ->
      new List.Header
```

With the above code, **I DO NOTICE** that "header" is appearing in the console, so it seems everything is alright with the HeaderApp.

show_view.js.coffee

```
@Demo.module "FooterApp.Show", (Show, App, Backbone, Marionette, $, _) ->

  class Show.Footer extends Marionette.ItemView
    template: "footer/show/templates/show_footer"
```

list_view.js.coffee

```
@Demo.module "HeaderApp.List", (List, App, Backbone, Marionette, $, _) ->

  class List.Header extends Marionette.ItemView
    template: "header/list/templates/list_header"
```

header_app.js.coffee

```
@Demo.module "HeaderApp", (HeaderApp, App, Backbone, Marionette, $, _) ->
  @startWithParent = false

  API =

    listHeader: ->
      HeaderApp.List.Controller.listHeader()

  HeaderApp.on "start", ->
    API.listHeader()
```

footer_app.js.coffee

```
@Demo.module "FooterApp", (FooterApp, App, Backbone, Marionette, $, _) ->
  @startWithParent = false

  API =

    showFooter: ->
      FooterApp.Show.Controller.showFooter()

  FooterApp.on "start", ->
    API.showFooter()
```

renderer.js.coffee

```
@Demo.module "FooterApp", (FooterApp, App, Backbone, Marionette, $, _) ->
  @startWithParent = false

  API =

    showFooter: ->
      FooterApp.Show.Controller.showFooter()

  FooterApp.on "start", ->
    API.showFooter()
```

app.js.coffee

```
console.log @

@Demo = do (Backbone, Marionette) ->

  App = new Marionette.Application

  App.addRegions
    headerRegion: "#header-region"
    mainRegion: "#main-region"
    footerRegion: "#footer-region"

  App.addInitializer ->
    App.module("HeaderApp").start()
    App.module("FooterApp").start()

  App.on "initialize:after", ->
    if Backbone.history
      Backbone.history.start()

  App
```

application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require lib/underscore
//= require lib/backbone
//= require lib/marionette
//= require_tree ./backbone/config  
//= require backbone/app
//= require_tree ./backbone/apps
```

application.css

```
@import "twitter/bootstrap";

@import "apps/base";

@import "apps/header";

@import "apps/footer";
```

Here is the directory structure:

```
app
  assets
    javascripts
      backbone
        apps
          footer
            show
              templates
                show_footer.jst.eco
              show_controller.js.coffee
              show_view.js.coffee
            footer_app.js.coffee
          header
            list
              templates
                list_header.jst.eco
              list_controller.js.coffee
              list_view.js.coffee
            header.app.js.coffee
        config
          marionette
            renderer.js.coffee
          app.js.coffee
        application.js
    stylesheets
      application.css
```

I'm wondering if all my path stuff is declared correctly based on my directory structure.

Thanks for any help, I'll be awaiting a response eagerly.

Answer (score 1):

Check the following:

1. The template paths are correct
2. You've properly overridden the he renderer in `renderer.js.coffee` and it's getting loaded properly in the HTML (i.e. you can see the code when you view the page's source)

If that looks correct, try comparing your code to the source code provided with the screencast.